# How do i clear the array

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to write a program that can read a string from Serial Monitor Input and count the size of characters as the input data and store the input to the array, but i have some trouble that the Serial monitor will remain the last input data  for example if I input ABC it will show "Size of input data =  3 characters" then i input ABC again it will remain the last data that i input before, I already reset it =0 what mistake do i make?

Serial monitor showing:

Please input

Size of input data =  3 characters

ABC

Please input

Please input

Size of input data =  7 characters

ABC

ABC

> here's my code:
>
> ```
> String Msg  ; 
> char buf[1200]={0} ;     // this is an array
> char input;
> int num=0;
> void setup() {
>   // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:  
>   Serial.begin(115200);
>   while (!Serial) 
>   {
>     ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
>   }
>    }
> ```

```
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available()) 
  {
    input = (char)Serial.read();
     if(input != '\n' ) 
    { 
      buf[num] = input;  
      Msg+=input;    
      num++;
     }
     else{
      buf[num++] = input;  // last character is newline
      buf[num] = 0;         // string array should be terminated with a zero
      Serial.println("Please input");
      Serial.print("Size of input data =  ");
      Serial.print(Msg.length());
      Serial.print(" characters");
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println(Msg);
      Serial.println("Please input");
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("");
        for(int i=0; i<num ;i++){
        Msg[i]=0;
        buf[i] =0;
        }
        
       
       }
       num=0;
       }
    return;
         }
```

Comment: sorry i have to correct it the Size of input data = 6 characters not 7 characters

Comment: your problem is not that you cannot clear the array. you fail to clear the String. At least that's what you print the content and size of. the array is not used in your output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Arduino manual the String `[]` operator does the same as `charAt()`.
As there is also a `setCharAt()` function I suppose `[]` and `charAt()` are read only.

The manual doesn't say that but why would they have a `setCharAt()` then.

Just assign an empty string to `Msg` to clear it.

```
Msg = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in the wrong way.

> Msg is a String type variable, not an array so you can just clear string like below.

```
Msg="";
```

> Don't use unnecessary for loop to clear a char buf array you can do it in a better way by using the memset function.

```
memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
```

and finally, take "num=0;" inside else loop so that it will be zero once completion not every time while loop is executing.

So final tested code will look like this,

```
String Msg  ;
char buf[1200] = {0} ;   // this is an array
char input;
int num = 0;
void setup() {
  // Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
  {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }
}
void loop() {
  while (Serial.available())
  {
    input = (char)Serial.read();
    if (input != '\n' )
    {
      buf[num] = input;
      Msg += input;
      num++;
    }
    else {
      buf[num++] = input;  // last character is newline
      buf[num] = 0;         // string array should be terminated with a zero
      Serial.println("Please input");
      Serial.print("Size of input data =  ");
      Serial.print(Msg.length());
      Serial.print(" characters");
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println(Msg);
      Serial.println("Please input");
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.println("");
      Msg ="";
      memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
      num = 0;
    }
    
  }
  return;
}
```